# Custom header is not added into request.META in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-rest-framework, custom-authentication

I implemented custom authentication, as described in [docs](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication)

```
# custom_permissions.py

from rest_framework import authentication
from rest_framework import exceptions

class KeyAuthentication(authentication.BaseAuthentication):
    def authenticate(self, request):
        key = request.META.get('Authorization')
        print(key)
        if not key:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Authentication failed.')

        try:
            key = ApiKey.objects.get(key=key)
        except ApiKey.DoesNotExist:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('Authentication failed.')

    return (key, None)
```

In my settings:

```
# settings.py

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'api_server.apps.api_v1.custom_permissions.KeyAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
}
```

It works as expected during tests:

```
def test_1(self):
    client = APIClient()
    client.credentials(X_SECRET_KEY='INVALID_KEY')
    response = client.get('/v1/resource/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 403)
    self.assertEqual(response.data, {'detail': 'Authentication failed.'})

def test_2(self):
    client = APIClient()
    client.credentials(X_SECRET_KEY='FEJ5UI')
    response = client.get('/v1/resource/')
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

However when I test with `curl` and locally running server, there is no `X_SECRET_KEY` header found in `request.META`. It is printing `None` in terminal, while received key is expected.

```
$ curl -X GET localhost:8080/v1/resource/ -H "X_SECRET_KEY=FEJ5UI"
{'detail': 'Authentication failed.'}
```

Could you give a hint, what might be a problem with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The headers variables are uppercase and prefixed with "HTTP_". This is general to Django, dunno about other languages / frameworks.

See https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/authentication.py#L23 for example.